# adding a column to Pandas dataframe based on adjacent values of existing column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with 3 columns: `time`(timestamp), `id` (str) and `red`(boolean). I want to add another boolean column that for each row checks if this row or any of the chronologically-next two rows of this id are red. (If there are less than two rows of the same id after this row, we only consider the rows that we have.)

What is an elegant way to do this? **My approach** was not elegant:
I sorted by time, created an empty list called `new_col` and filled it in a loop over all rows of `df` by:

(`for row_number in xrange(len(df)-2)...`)

using `iloc` and then typed `df['col']=new_col`. This is slow and not very readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you first sort by timestamp, you could group by id, and for each group, shift the values of `red` once and twice, and find the logical or of the result:

```
 df['col'] = df.red.groupby(df.id).apply(lambda g: g | g.shift(-1) | g.shift(-2))
```

For example:

```
In [100]: df = pd.DataFrame({'red': [True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True], 'id': [0] * 6 + [1] * 2})

In [101]: df.red.groupby(df.id).apply(lambda g: g | g.shift(-1) | g.shift(-2))
Out[101]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
Name: red, dtype: bool
```

Comment: How do I incorporate the `id` part of the question?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ami, with the slight caveat that I believe you only want to check subsequent rows for red / not red, thus I would remove the first `OR` statement within the `groupby`:

```
# df1 (original df)
#   id    red        time
# 0  1   True  2016-09-01
# 1  1   True  2016-09-02
# 2  1   True  2016-09-03
# 3  2   True  2016-09-02
# 4  3  False  2016-09-03
# 5  4  False  2016-09-04
# 6  5  False  2016-09-05

df2 = df1.groupby(['id'])['red'].apply(lambda g: g.shift(-1) | g.shift(-2)).reset_index()
df2.drop(labels='index', axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={0: 'next red'}, inplace=True)
df1.join(other=df2)
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
  id    red        time next red
0  1   True  2016-09-01     True
1  1   True  2016-09-02     True
2  1   True  2016-09-03    False
3  2   True  2016-09-02    False
4  3  False  2016-09-03    False
5  4  False  2016-09-04    False
6  5  False  2016-09-05    False
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer, because after reading the question, I'm not sure you're not correct in your interpretation.